# Use shell to delete all conflict files using xargs

Tags: shell, grep, dropbox, xargs, rm

I'm trying to get rid off all my Dropbox files including "File foo in conflict with copy from ..." I tried several lines of code but non of them worked so far :(

```
find | grep conflict | xargs -0 rm ""
```

Error: filename too long for rm because there is no file/line separator
When i use the following:

```
find | grep conflict | head -1 | xargs rm ""
```

I get errors because the filename contains spaces. What line of code should I choose to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need `xargs`, you can do it directly with `find`:

```
find . -name '*conflict*' -delete
```

Alternatively, you could execute `rm`:

```
find . -name '*conflict*' -exec rm -- {} \+
```

`--` prevents problems with file names that start with a dash. <sub>(Hat tip: [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0))</sub>

Comment: `-delete` is a GNU find-ism I believe.

Comment: @EtanReisner Turns out it is!

Comment: Nicely done; while `-delete` is nonstandard, BSD / OSX `find` supports it as well. The `-exec` solution is POSIX-compliant (if you want to be extra-super robust, use `-exec rm -- {} +`).

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, added! My find (GNU findutils 4.4.2) doesn't mention BSD/OSX in the "also appears" for `-delete`. All the better if it works anyway. ETA: definitely mentioned on the [manpage](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)).

Comment: Thanks for adding `--`. The `find` version that comes with OSX 10.10.5 doesn't support printing version information, unfortunately (which, incidentally, tells us that it's not GNU `find` - OSX _does_ come with a few GNU utilities); however, the man page says "BSD General Commands Manual" and "September 28, 2011". It definitely mentions `-delete`, and I've just verified that it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name '*conflict*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```